Why does it return Bad Gateway on Flask App in Python
I am encountering a bad gateway error due to this error in NGINX:
2024/10/01 02:53:38 [crit] 383343#383343: *153 connect() to unix:/home/ubuntu/ip-whitelister/ip-whitelister.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream

But, the sock is already in 777 permission

Here's my NGINX config:
server {
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/ip-whitelister/ip-whitelister.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}


First of all, you have to check the socket file is valid.
The file /home/ubuntu/ip-whitelister/ip-whitelister.sock seems to be a symbolic link.
ls -l /home/ubuntu/ip-whitelister/ip-whitelister.sock

Check where the actual location is, and the permission setting of real socket file.
Then you have to check the permission of parent directory.
If the permission setting of the '/home/ubuntu' or '/home/ubuntu/ip-whitelister' and the parent directories of the real location is something like 750 or 770, it wouldn't be able to access that either.
Or you can just move the file to a public directory so that every user could access it, just for testing. It's ok.
Once finishing permission setting, if NGINX can still not access the socket file, maybe you have to check the AppArmor. It might restrict application from accessing something.
Finally, if it doesn't work at all, and you'd really want to publish your website, you can try to expose flask port on localhost interface, and do reverse proxy for this.

it's not a symbolic link. it returns:
root@ip-*********:~# ls -l /home/ubuntu/ip-whitelister/ip-whitelister.sock
srwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu www-data 0 Oct  1 03:35 /home/ubuntu/ip-whitelister/ip-whitelister.sock
